# How to find blank pages inside a PDF using PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf

Here is the challenge I'm currently facing.
I have a lot of PDFs and I have to remove the blank pages inside them and display only the pages with content (text or images).
The problem is that those pdfs are scanned documents.
So the blank pages have some dirty left behind by the scanner.

Comment: So essentially you're PDFs contain an image power page and you want to know whether that image represents an empty pageor not. Pdfbox can help you extract that image bit it is no imaged analysis tool.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did some research and ended up with this code that checks for 99% of the page as white or light gray.
I needed the gray factor as the scanned documents sometimes are not pure white.

```
private static Boolean isBlank(PDPage pdfPage) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = pdfPage.convertToImage();
    long count = 0;
    int height = bufferedImage.getHeight();
    int width = bufferedImage.getWidth();
    Double areaFactor = (width * height) * 0.99;

    for (int x = 0; x < width ; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height ; y++) {
            Color c = new Color(bufferedImage.getRGB(x, y));
            // verify light gray and white
            if (c.getRed() == c.getGreen() && c.getRed() == c.getBlue()
                    && c.getRed() >= 248) {
                 count++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (count >= areaFactor) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Amazing solution. Thank you so much. This solution also works where there is content like "This Page is Intentionally left blank."

Comment: can you please explain the `Double areaFactor = (width * height) * 0.99;`?

Comment: This is cpu intensive task

Comment: @PrameshBajracharya this calculates the area (width * height) and then 99% of that area (.99). The loop counts pixels that match the condition, so if that count exceeds the computed 99% area, the page is "blank" enough.

Comment: Nice solution, but you should count "black" pixels instead of white, because if you will found 1% of black pixels, it will mean that page "is not blank" instead of scan all page for searhing 99% of white pixels.

Answer (score 4):

@Shoyo's code works fine for **PDFBox version < 2.0**. For future readers, there's no much change but, just in case, here is the code for **PDFBOX 2.0+** to make your life easier.

In your `main` (By main, I mean the place where you are loading your PDF into PDDocument) method:

```
try {
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("/home/codemantra/Downloads/tetml_ct_access/C.pdf"));
    PDFRenderer renderedDoc = new PDFRenderer(document);
    for (int pageNumber = 0; pageNumber < document.getNumberOfPages(); pageNumber++) {
        if(isBlank(renderedDoc.renderImage(pageNumber))) {
            System.out.println("Blank Page Number : " + pageNumber + 1);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And `isBlank` method will just have `BufferedImage` passed in:

```
private static Boolean isBlank(BufferedImage pageImage) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = pageImage;
    long count = 0;
    int height = bufferedImage.getHeight();
    int width = bufferedImage.getWidth();
    Double areaFactor = (width * height) * 0.99;

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            Color c = new Color(bufferedImage.getRGB(x, y));
            if (c.getRed() == c.getGreen() && c.getRed() == c.getBlue() && c.getRed() >= 248) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (count >= areaFactor) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

> **All the credits goes to @Shoyo**

**Update:**

Some PDFs have **"This Page was Intentionally Left Blank"** to which the above code considers as blank. If this is your requirement then feel free to use the above code. But, my requirement was only to filter out the pages that were completely blank (No any images present nor consisting of any fonts). So, I ended up using this code (Plus this code runs faster :P) :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("/home/codemantra/Downloads/CTP2040.pdf"));
        PDPageTree allPages = document.getPages();
        Integer pageNumber = 1;
        for (PDPage page : allPages) {
            Iterable<COSName> xObjects = page.getResources().getXObjectNames();
            Iterable<COSName> fonts = page.getResources().getFontNames();
            if(xObjects.spliterator().getExactSizeIfKnown() == 0 && fonts.spliterator().getExactSizeIfKnown() == 0) {
                System.out.println(pageNumber);                 
            }
            pageNumber++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This will return the page numbers of those pages which are completely blank.

*Hope this helps someone! :)*

Comment: Hi, I got an error saying that 'groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
java.util.Collections$EmptySet.spliterator() is applicable for argument types: () values:
[]
Possible solutions: iterator(), iterator(), iterator()' , could you please take a look?

Comment: @qifengwu Hey, the `spliterator()` method should be by default available in `java.lang.Iterable<COSName>`. You might want to change your default java compiler to 1.8 and try. Just as a reference, please have a look at `Spliterator<COSName> java.lang.Iterable.spliterator()` too. Check out for PDFBox version. I had some problem in versions. I am using 2.0.6. I hope this helps. Please let me know if you need any help and if you got this resolved. Also, consider posting a comment if you solved this. It can help others :)

Comment: I always have 1 image on page, and this image could be just white rectangle. It happen because people scan real document and convert scanned reuslts into pdf.

Comment: Yes @degr, you are right. People literally generate PDFs from thin air these days. I have been working with PDFs for a while now and the only solid thing I can conclude is that you could never be 100% accurate in case of these PDFs (But we could try).

Answer (score 0):

@Pramesh Bajracharya, Your solution to find a blank page in a PDF document is intact!

If in case the requirement is to remove the blank pages the same code can be enhanced as below

```
      List<Integer> blankPageList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for( PDPage page : allPages )
      {
        Iterable<COSName> xObjects = page.getResources().getXObjectNames();
        Iterable<COSName> fonts = page.getResources().getFontNames();
        // condition to determine if the page is a blank page
        if( xObjects.spliterator().getExactSizeIfKnown() == 0 && fonts.spliterator().getExactSizeIfKnown() == 0 )
        {
          pageRemovalList.add( pageNumber );
        }
        pageNumber++;
      }

      // remove the blank pages from the pdf document using the blank page numbers list
      for( Integer i : blankPageList )
      {
        document.removePage( i );
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-detect-and-remove-blank-page-in-pdf.html

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.io.RandomAccessSourceFactory;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDictionary;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray;

public class RemoveBlankPageFromPDF {

    // value where we can consider that this is a blank image
    // can be much higher or lower depending of what is considered as a blank page
    public static final int BLANK_THRESHOLD = 160;

    public static void removeBlankPdfPages(String source, String destination)
        throws IOException, DocumentException
    {
        PdfReader r = null;
        RandomAccessSourceFactory rasf = null;
        RandomAccessFileOrArray raf = null;
        Document document = null;
        PdfCopy writer = null;

        try {
            r = new PdfReader(source);
            // deprecated
            //    RandomAccessFileOrArray raf
            //           = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(pdfSourceFile);
            // itext 5.4.1
            rasf = new RandomAccessSourceFactory();
            raf = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(rasf.createBestSource(source));
            document = new Document(r.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));
            writer = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(destination));
            document.open();
            PdfImportedPage page = null;

            for (int i=1; i<=r.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                // first check, examine the resource dictionary for /Font or
                // /XObject keys.  If either are present -> not blank.
                PdfDictionary pageDict = r.getPageN(i);
                PdfDictionary resDict = (PdfDictionary) pageDict.get( PdfName.RESOURCES );
                boolean noFontsOrImages = true;
                if (resDict != null) {
                  noFontsOrImages = resDict.get( PdfName.FONT ) == null &&
                                    resDict.get( PdfName.XOBJECT ) == null;
                }
                System.out.println(i + " noFontsOrImages " + noFontsOrImages);

                if (!noFontsOrImages) {
                    byte bContent [] = r.getPageContent(i,raf);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bs.write(bContent);
                    System.out.println
                      (i + bs.size() + " > BLANK_THRESHOLD " +  (bs.size() > BLANK_THRESHOLD));
                    if (bs.size() > BLANK_THRESHOLD) {
                        page = writer.getImportedPage(r, i);
                        writer.addPage(page);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (document != null) document.close();
            if (writer != null) writer.close();
            if (raf != null) raf.close();
            if (r != null) r.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main (String ... args) throws Exception {
        removeBlankPdfPages
            ("C://temp//documentwithblank.pdf", "C://temp//documentwithnoblank.pdf");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are aware that the op asked for a pdfbox solution and you provide code using iText?

Comment: Mkl is right, I wanted a pdfbox solution.
I saw that solution on my researches, but since it's a scanned document the bytes checking is not precise.
I have blank pages with more bytes than pages with images.
Thanks for the interest though....